# I'am trying to add new field of the product price attribute value (msrp, map ) on storefront

Tags: orocommerce

Here is the code i am trying to use

```
    -  '@add':  
            id: price_attribute_product_price
            parentId: product_view_specification
            blockType: product_prices
            options:
                label: visible
```

but it doesn't do anything!
Am i missing something?

Comment: i have to create a layout data provider to get a price attribute per product and then add a block to the storefront!

Answer (score 0):

That's how we did it too, although ours is hard-coded to the RRP attribute but it's pretty easy to customize this.

Sharing our code as I think it's been asked quite a few times in the community before.

We created our own custom Price Provider:

```php
namespace Aligent\BaseBundle\Provider;

use Oro\Bundle\CurrencyBundle\Entity\Price;
use Oro\Bundle\EntityBundle\ORM\DoctrineHelper;
use Oro\Bundle\PricingBundle\Entity\PriceAttributePriceList;
use Oro\Bundle\PricingBundle\Entity\PriceAttributeProductPrice;
use Oro\Bundle\PricingBundle\Provider\PriceAttributePricesProvider;
use Oro\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Product;

/**
 * Makes the rrp price attribute available.
 * The rrp price attribute can be found in db table: oro_price_attribute_pl
 */
class RRPPriceProvider
{
    const PRICE_ATTRIBUTE = 'RRP';

    protected DoctrineHelper $doctrineHelper;
    protected PriceAttributePricesProvider $priceAttributePricesProvider;

    /**
     * @param DoctrineHelper $doctrineHelper
     * @param PriceAttributePricesProvider $priceAttributePricesProvider
     */
    public function __construct(
        DoctrineHelper $doctrineHelper,
        PriceAttributePricesProvider $priceAttributePricesProvider
    ) {
        $this->doctrineHelper = $doctrineHelper;
        $this->priceAttributePricesProvider = $priceAttributePricesProvider;
    }


    /**
     * Get RRP price with unit and currencies from custom Product Price Attribute Price List
     * @param Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRRPPriceWithUnitAndCurrencies(Product $product) : array
    {
        /** @var PriceAttributePriceList $rrpPriceList */
        $rrpPriceList = $this->getRRPAttributePriceList();

        return $this->priceAttributePricesProvider->getPricesWithUnitAndCurrencies($rrpPriceList, $product);
    }

    /**
     * Get RRP price from custom Product Price Attribute Price List
     * @param Product $product
     * @return Price|null
     */
    public function getRRPPrice(Product $product) : ?Price
    {
        /** @var PriceAttributePriceList $rrpPriceList */
        $rrpPriceList = $this->getRRPAttributePriceList();

        /** @var PriceAttributeProductPrice $priceAttributePrice */
        $priceAttributePrice = $this->doctrineHelper
            ->getEntityRepository(PriceAttributeProductPrice::class)
            ->findOneBy(['product' => $product, 'priceList' => $rrpPriceList]);

        return $priceAttributePrice?->getPrice();
    }

    /**
     * Gets just the RRP Price Attribute Price List
     * @return PriceAttributePriceList|null
     */
    protected function getRRPAttributePriceList() : PriceAttributePriceList
    {
        return $this->doctrineHelper->getEntityRepository(PriceAttributePriceList::class)->findOneBy([
            'name' => self::PRICE_ATTRIBUTE,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And then we have a Layout DataProvider to make this available in the layouts:

```php
namespace Aligent\BaseBundle\Layout\DataProvider;

use Aligent\BaseBundle\Provider\RRPPriceProvider;
use Oro\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Product;

class RRPPriceLayoutProvider
{
    protected RRPPriceProvider $rrpPriceProvider;

    public function __construct(RRPPriceProvider $RRPPriceProvider)
    {
        $this->rrpPriceProvider = $RRPPriceProvider;
    }

    /**
     * Get RRP price with unit and currencies from custom Product Price Attribute Price List
     * Called from layout.yml via: =data["product_rrp_price"].getRRPPriceWithUnitAndCurrencies(data["entity"])'
     */
    public function getRRPPriceWithUnitAndCurrencies(Product $product) : array
    {
        return $this->rrpPriceProvider->getRRPPriceWithUnitAndCurrencies($product);
    }

    /**
     * Get RRP price from custom Product Price Attribute Price List
     * Called from layout.yml via: =data["product_rrp_price"].getRRPPrice(data["entity"])'
     */
    public function getRRPPrice(Product $product) : ?string
    {
        return $this->rrpPriceProvider->getRRPPrice($product)?->getValue();
    }
}
```

services.yml:

```yaml
services:
    # Providers
    Aligent\BaseBundle\Provider\RRPPriceProvider:
        arguments:
            - '@oro_api.doctrine_helper'
            - '@oro_pricing.providers.price_attribute_prices'

    # Layout Providers
    Aligent\BaseBundle\Layout\DataProvider\RRPPriceLayoutProvider:
        arguments:
            - '@Aligent\BaseBundle\Provider\RRPPriceProvider'
        tags:
            - { name: layout.data_provider, alias: product_rrp_price }
```

And then actually call it from your `layout.yml`:

```yaml
layout:
  actions:
    - '@add':
        id: product_rrp_price
        parentId: product_price_container
        blockType: container
        options:
            vars:
                rrp_price_data: '=data["product_rrp_price"].getRRPPrice(data["product"])'
```

### Additional Considerations

Your own use case may require customization (such as multiple attributes), and potentially a caching layer for performance reasons (such as storing the list of Price Attribute Price Lists in Redis etc instead of fetching them each time). If you plan on displaying this information on the PLP/Search pages I'd strongly recommend also including the price attributes in your search index rather than querying them for each of the 25 products per page.